# Datatable not being responsive after adding many columns

Tags: javascript, html

My datatable is not being responsive after I specified all the column to be appear. Let's say today I put the following code:

```
<table id="tableWithdrawalList" class="display responsive nowrap  table table-striped table-lightfont" style="width:100%; border-top:1px solid grey;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="text-left"><input type="checkbox" title="Select all" id="selectedAllRadio" onclick="checkUnCheckAll()" /></th>
            <th class="text-left">Request Receipt</th>
            <th class="text-left">Created Date</th>
            <th class="text-left">Serial Number</th>
            <th class="text-left">Full Name</th>
            <th class="text-left">Email</th>
            <th class="text-left">Amount</th>
            <th class="text-left">Processing Fee</th>
            <th class="text-left">Assigned To</th>
            <th class="text-left">Assigned Time</th>
            <th class="text-left">Status</th>
            <th class="text-left">Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

the result become

[image]

it fit well no problem. However they not displaying the column I mentioned in the datatable, it only show until processing fee.

Let's say now I specify all column

```
<table id="tableWithdrawalList" class="display responsive nowrap  table table-striped table-lightfont" style="width:100%; border-top:1px solid grey;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="all text-left"><input type="checkbox" title="Select all" id="selectedAllRadio" onclick="checkUnCheckAll()" /></th>
            <th class="all text-left">Request Receipt</th>
            <th class="all text-left">Created Date</th>
            <th class="all text-left">Serial Number</th>
            <th class="all text-left">Full Name</th>
            <th class="all text-left">Email</th>
            <th class="all text-left">Amount</th>
            <th class="all text-left">Processing Fee</th>
            <th class="all text-left">Assigned To</th>
            <th class="all text-left">Assigned Time</th>
            <th class="all text-left">Status</th>
            <th class="all text-left">Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

[image]
Oh my god, the datatable cross the panel without being responsive, how I can display all column with responsive?

Comment: You cant. You need to use horizontal scroll to view all columns. or you could hide some of the column and only show the importand ones when the screen is xpx.

Comment: So you need the column to be vertical right? otherwise how would you know what data belong to what column? are you using some kind of library ?

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to show all columns, I think you can try to adjust individual column width to fit nicely. Also, add this css property `table-layout:fixed;` to `#tableWithdrawalList` to force the text break in the table.

Hope it helps.